# How can i use the curve Goodness of Fit?

Tags: matlab, signal-processing

I would like to use the the curve Goodness of Fit (GOF) in order to compare the rate of resemblance between the orignal signal and the filtered signal in Matlab

Answer (score 1):

Normally, a goodness-of-fit test presumes a comparison between empirical data and theoretical data... in other words, between the real observations and the values produced by a function that approximates them. Since you are working with curves, the [fit function](https://mathworks.com/help/curvefit/fit.html) already provides all what you need in order to perform the test:

```
[fitobject,gof] = fit(x,y,fitType)

  gof — Goodness-of-fit statistics, returned as the gof structure including the fields in this table:

    sse - Sum of squares due to error
    rsquare - R-squared (coefficient of determination)
    dfe - Degrees of freedom in the error
    adjrsquare - Degree-of-freedom adjusted coefficient of determination
    rmse - Root mean squared error (standard error)
```

Let's make an example:

```
x = (0:0.2:5).';
y = 2 .* exp(-0.2 .* x);

[f1,gof1] = fit(x,y,'exp1');
figure(),plot(f1,x,y);

[f2,gof2] = fit(x,y,'poly1');
figure(),plot(f2,x,y);
```

From the declaration of `y`, since no noise is being added to it, we know that an exponential fit with `a = 2` and `b = -0.2` would produce a perfect result, while the polynomial fit would produce a good (but not perfect) result.

The R2 statistic can take any value between `0` and `1`, with a value closer to `1` indicating a better fit. Since we are not playing with additional coefficients, it's more than enough to evaluate our fits and represents a good criterion for choosing a model between many. Looking at the R2 values contained in the `gof1` and `gof2` structures (`rsquare` field), we can see that our hypotesis is confirmed: in `gof1` the R2 statistic has a value of `1` (perfect fit), while in `gof2` the same statistic has a value very close to `1` but not equal to `1` (very good fit).